# Why does my Random Number Generator not print any 1's?

Tags: c

I made this randomNumberGenerator for a project of mine. It prints all numbers between 1 and 9 randomly, but not the number 1. The if-statements are there to get rid of any consecutive numbers (123 or 555 f.e.). What can I do to make sure it also is able to print 1's. All help is welcome!

The fp part which handles my file should not be relevant to the issue.

Edit: I work in Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int n = 3000;
    int randomNumber;
    int lastNumber;

    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("C:\\Users\\furtherDirectoryToFile", "w");

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lastNumber = randomNumber;
        randomNumber = rand() % 10;
        if (randomNumber == lastNumber) {
            continue;
        } else {
            if (randomNumber == ((lastNumber + 1) || randomNumber == (lastNumber - 1))) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", randomNumber);
        fprintf (fp, "%d\n", randomNumber);
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to initialize `randomNumber` before entering the loop.

Comment: 1.) be aware that `lastNumber` is always the last random number you generated, even if you didn't display it, so you could easily display the same number twice. 2.) also note that "random number" kind of implies that the same number (or one just 1 bigger or smaller) can definitely occur and still be random, any attempt to make these random numbers "more random" with rules like that actually **reduces randomness** (which may be what you want, but if your goal is to "increase randomness", then this approach is misguided).

Comment: Yes: setting `randomNumber = 99` means the *first* time through the loop won't ever be rejected.  Also, if you want numbers 1-9 you probably want to set `randomNumber = (rand() % 9) + 1`, which produces that range.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Thanks for the first part. I needed a range of 0-9 so I think what I already had in regards to the rand() function is OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, that your parentheses are set wrong in the if-clause. You need:

```
if ((randomNumber == (lastNumber + 1)) || (randomNumber == (lastNumber - 1)))
```

instead you have

```
(randomNumber == 
       ( (lastNumber + 1) || randomNumber == (lastNumber - 1)))
```

which evaluates to

```
(randomNumber == 1)
```

This is why you never observe a 1.

Further comments:

It, in general, does not make your random numbers more secure if you try to inhibit sequences; on the contrary, if someone knows this algorithm, he can make assumptions on the next digit, which he couldn't make otherwise.

From comments:

As moooeeeep commented, you should initialize the variable `randomNumber` before you use it first.

JoachimSauer noticed, that `lastNumber` should only be set if the number is indeed output, otherwise your algorithm can fail.

And as SteveFriedl commented, if you need the range `1-9` instead of `0-9`, then use `randomNumber = rand() % 9 + 1;`

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much. I needed a range of 0-9 so with what SteveFriedl said it fixed the issue.